# Need to Check running app has admin privileges or not in C#.Net Compact Framework

Tags: c#, windows, security, windows-embedded-compact

Is there any way to check the admin privileges in C#.Net Compact Framework??

I have the source code from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in C++.

and

This will check if user is in the local Administrators group (assuming you're not checking for domain admin permissions):

```
using System.Security.Principal;

public bool IsUserAdministrator()
{
    //bool value to hold our return value
    bool isAdmin;
    try
    {
        //get the currently logged in user
        WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
        WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
        isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        isAdmin = false;
    }
    return isAdmin;
}
```

But `using System.Security.Principal;` is not available in **C#.NET CF**

Is it possible to implement the same in **C#Net CF.**

Comment: The main purpose of .Net Compact Framework is to target mobile platforms, so there are no admin privileges questions.
Why are you using .Net CF here?